# Mono on Linux - GetDrives does not return all drives

Tags: c#, linux, mono

The `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives` method does not seem to return all mounts when running on CentOS under Mono 3.2.5

Is anyone aware of a problem or a workaround (such as manually parsing /proc/self/mounts)?

**Edit**

I submitted a bug with Mono. I doesn't seem right that a couple of network mounts that show in `df` don't get reported by Mono when many others do, including most network drives.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17398

Luke

Comment: Should work, maybe it broken with the package delivered with CentOS. Because I saw some snippet that output all mounted partition on Ubuntu. Maybe you can try to download a recent source package of Mono and compile it.

Comment: There's now PowerShell for Linux/Mono (Pash) so you'd think `Get-Drives` would have exhibited this issue. Mind you, my understanding of Linux drives vs. mounts and volumes is limited, so maybe there's some semantics of what a qualifies as a drive.